# Swift: casting Optional<AnyObject> to TimeInterval error

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift3

I am trying to cast `Optional<AnyObject>` to `TimeInterval` object from different sources. But I am facing the following issue:

**Case 1: From JSON file**

I have a JSON file

```
{
 ...
 "dispatchInterval":50,
 ...
}
```

Then I create a dictionary with `JSONSerialization`.

```
let settingJson = try? String(contentsOfFile:filePath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

cofigDict:[String:AnyObject] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: settingJson.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

So the type of `configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval]` is 
`Optional(AnyObject)`. And casting it to `TimeInterval` works (interval is not **nil** but is set to 50):

```
let interval = configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval] as? TimeInterval
```

**Case 2: From Dictionary**

Here I am using dictionary to set the interval value.

```
 let configDict = [... "dispatchInterval":50, ...] as [String : AnyObject]
```

Here we do not need `JSONSerialization`.

Similarly here also the type of `configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval]` is 
`Optional(AnyObject)`.

But casting it to `TimeInterval` does not work (interval is `nil`).

This should not happen as I checked the type of `configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval]` for both cases. It was `Optional(AnyObject)` only.

Also is there any way that

```
let interval = configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval] as? TimeInterval
```

works for both cases?

Comment: I think your code looks like it should work. Can you provide an mcve that reproduces this problem? Something that I can just run in a playground and see the the results you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do  it Like  that :

```
 let interval : TimeInterval? =   configDict[ConfigKey.dispatchInterval]?.doubleValue
```

Comment: Could you explain what was the issue?

Comment: can't convert AnyObject to Timeinterval its double value not object

Comment: But what is the difference between the cases? It works fine if it taken from json file or json string even though it was AnyObject.

Comment: are you Devine it as  string :AnyObject

Comment: https://craiggrummitt.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/anyanyobject.png?w=419&h=419&zoom=2